# How to add sound and vibration notifications in Expo?

Tags: javascript, react-native, push-notification, expo

I have a text notification in a simple notes app, which is displayed when the date is due.

I want to add:

- sound and vibration to this notification
- and that the banner with the text remains on the screen until you manually enter the application.

I have reviewed documentation but I can't get the sound or vibration to work, only the text banner works.

I tried to implement `import { Audio } from "expo-av"` and I have tried to add `import { Vibration } from "react-native"` , but only the Banner works.

Take a look at my code and you'll see what I'm doing wrong.

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { Audio } from "expo-av";
import * as Notifications from "expo-notifications";
import { Alert } from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";

Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
  handleNotification: async () => {
    return {
      shouldPlaySound: true,
      shouldSetBadge: false,
      shouldShowAlert: true,
    };
  },
});

const HandleNotifications = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [sound, setSound] = React.useState(null);

  async function loadSound() {
    const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
      require("../assets/sonido.mp3") // Reemplaza con la ruta correcta a tu archivo de sonido
    );
    setSound(sound);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    async function configurePushNotifications() {
      const { status } = await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
      let finalStatus = status;

      if (finalStatus !== "granted") {
        const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
        finalStatus = status;
      }

      if (finalStatus !== "granted") {
        Alert.alert(
          "Permiso requerido",
          "Se requieren notificaciones locales para recibir alertas cuando vencen los recordatorios."
        );
        return;
      }

      if (finalStatus === "granted") {
        await loadSound();
      }
    }

    configurePushNotifications();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener(
      (response) => {
        console.log("RESPONSE", response);
        const reminderId =
          response.notification.request.content.data.reminderId;
        if (reminderId) {
          // @ts-ignore
          navigation.navigate("ModifyReminder", { reminderId });
        }
      }
    );

    return () => {
      subscription.remove();
      if (sound) {
        sound.unloadAsync();
      }
    };
  });

  return <React.Fragment />;
};

export default HandleNotifications;
```

**I EDIT THE QUESTION TO ADD DETAILS**

I've gotten some sneak peeks, and with the following tweak, the music plays, but it plays constantly, since we open the app.
however, it does not ring when it should ring, when the marked date is fulfilled.
Vibration doesn't work either.

Of course I've gone through @RRR's detailed suggestions, but I can't get it to work.

I'm not doing things right, and the worst thing is that I don't know where to go looking for ideas.

See the code and discover my mistakes

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";
import * as Notifications from "expo-notifications";
import { Alert, Vibration } from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { Audio } from 'expo-av';

Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
  handleNotification: async () => {
    return {
      shouldPlaySound: true,
      shouldSetBadge: false,
      shouldShowAlert: true,
    };
  },
});

const HandleNotifications = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function configurePushNotifications() {
      const { status } = await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
      let finalStatus = status;
      if (finalStatus !== "granted") {
        const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
        finalStatus = status;
      }
      if (finalStatus !== "granted") {
        Alert.alert(
          "Permiso requerido",
          "Se requieren notificaciones locales para recibir alertas cuando vencen los recordatorios."
        );
        return;
      }
    }

    configurePushNotifications();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener(
      (response) => {
        console.log("RESPONSE", response);
        const reminderId = response.notification.request.content.data.reminderId;
        if (reminderId) {
          navigation.navigate("ModifyReminder", { reminderId });
        }
      }
    );

    return () => subscription.remove();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    let soundObject = null;

    async function playSound() {
      soundObject = new Audio.Sound();
      try {
        await soundObject.loadAsync(require('../assets/sonido.mp3'));
        await soundObject.playAsync();
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }

    playSound();

    return () => {
      if (soundObject) {
        soundObject.stopAsync();
        soundObject.unloadAsync();
      }
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const appFocusSubscription = Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener(() => {
      Vibration.cancel();
      Audio.setIsEnabledAsync(false);
    });

    const appBlurSubscription = Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener(() => {
      Audio.setIsEnabledAsync(true);
    });

    return () => {
      appFocusSubscription.remove();
      appBlurSubscription.remove();
    };
  }, []);

  return <React.Fragment />;
};

export default HandleNotifications;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find two libraries I use regularly to achieve this :

For the vibration
https://reactnative.dev/docs/vibration

For the audio notification
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sound

You need to take car the permissions, which is generally the critical point on this topic :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @PorzioJonathan . As you'll see in my code, I already implemented one of those methods and went through the documentation before coming here for help. As you can see, it doesn't work and another of the links can't be used in Expo. Thanks for your advice, I'll keep looking.